# Samsung SCX-3201 MFP scanner not working

Tags: printing, samsung, sane, scanner

I have a Samsung SCX-3201 MFP multifunction printer and after plugging it into the computer it recognises the printer part, but the scanner is not detected.

Since that I've fresh installed and did not try it again. The built-in scan application nor SANE detects it.

I did try Samsung's proprietary software.Neither did it detect it

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10? See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1707352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Not Supported

Having checked the stable version of the SANE libraries that is included in Ubuntu from the [sane-project website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55103/samsung-scx-3201-mfp-scanner-not-working), the scanner in question is not yet supported.

To double check this you'll need your USB identifier that you can obtain using `lsusb`.

The SCX range of scanners use the [sane-xerox_mfp](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-xerox_mfp.5.html) back-end.

Checking the [unstable version](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-SAMSUNG) (the version you will need to compile from GIT source) again your scanner is not supported.

### Possible solution

Possibly you can add your model if it is similar to one of the listed models in the above links.  This involves adding the USB ID to `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` together with similar information to the SANE rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`

Obviously change the values to match your scanner.

To give you an example add the following text to `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`:

```
#Samsung CLX-3185FW
usb 0x04e8 0x343d
```

and `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` by adding

```
# Samsung CLX-3185FW
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="343d", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Make sure you install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

<sub>[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660550)</sub>

If the above does not work, try also adding your user account to groups `lp` and `scanner` by:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp [username]
sudo usermod -a -G scanner [username]
```

Comment: Hi fossfreedom (and others)! There are a similar problem at http://askubuntu.com/questions/758046/samsung-scx-4200-scanner-not-working-printing-ok-14-04, but with some differences. The problem there is not the support, I think, but I don't know what could by. Can you help us?