# Samsung SCX-4200 Scanner not working (printing OK) 14.04

Tags: samsung, scanner

I have somehow lost the possiblity of scanning using my Samsung SCX-4200 3in1 printer. Priting works fine using the Linux driver, provided at initial instalation, however scanning stalls and fails.

sane-find-scanner reveals:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.
  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Generic], product=0x0129 [USB2.0-CRW]) at libusb:001:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.
  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Plus, when I try scanimage -L, another computer in my network is shown, not the Samsung one.

```
scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/net/Deskjet_3520_series?zc=HPC8CBB850038A' is a Hewlett-Packard Deskjet_3520_series all-in-one
```

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of an old question, but I had similar issues in Ubuntu 18.04.

The problem in my case was USB3. After putting the cable to an USB2 input, it worked all fine.

This has been discussed here (in french language): https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2023391

*Might be related to this one:* [scanner of Samsung SCX-4200 does not work on ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305110/scanner-of-samsung-scx-4200-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-12-10)