# Samsung M2070W scanner no longer working in 17.10

Tags: scanner, samsung

I own a Samsung M2070W printer/scanner, which worked in 17.04.  After installing 17.10, it prints but is not detected my Simple Scan or Xsane.

The latest drivers from the Samsung website are installed.

It is detected by sane-find-scanner but not scanimage-L. Output from the former:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3469 [M2070 Series]) at libusb:003:003
```

I tried modifying the `.bashrc` as suggested in [Samsung SCX-4200 Scanner not working (printing OK) 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758046/samsung-scx-4200-scanner-not-working-printing-ok-14-04), but it didn't work.

I've seen this issue on several forums but no one seems to have a solution.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1707352

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not tech-savvy enough to know what to do with that information? Does it mean the bug is now fixed?

Comment: it means that many people do have this problem and it is not fixed. somebody changed something, did not test it very well, and thousands of users cannot scan now.

Answer (score 24):

I just got the scanner from Samsung M2070FW running with Ubuntu 18.04. Just follow these steps:

1. Get `UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.37.tar.gz` from [this site](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suld.html) and unpack it, open a terminal and do:

   ```
   cd /UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.37/uld
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```
2. After successful installation of the Samsung Driver for the printer and the scanner, you can installer the printer first via [Cups](http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-add-a-printer-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint-with-cups). For the scanner however, there should be a new directory with a single file in it:

   ```
   /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1
   ```
3. If you use a 64-bit system (which you probably do), use the terminal again to change to the scanner driver directory. Here you put a symbolic link to the file in `/opt`:

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
   sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1
   ```
4. But things still didn't work, so I had to install a USB library:

   ```
   sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4
   ```

   After that, I made sure that I was in the same network with my printer (via `ping`) and did `scanimage -L`:

   ```
   $ scanimage -L
   device `smfp:net;192.168.1.20' is a Samsung M2070 Series on 192.168.1.20 Scanner
   ```
5. If pinging your scanner works but the command finds nothing, you can start to debug things:

   ```
   cd
   export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255 && scanimage -L &> debug.txt
   grep -n2 "libsane-smf" debug.txt
   ```

   If everything works correctly, you would get the following output:

   ```
   ....
   84-[dll] sane_get_devices
   85-[dll] load: searching backend `smfp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane'
   86:[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'
   87:[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'
   88-[dll] init: initializing backend `smfp'
   89-[dll] init: backend `smfp' is version 1.0.1
   ....
   ```

   If not, you might find a hint as to what file is missing or not found.

Comment: Did everything you described, and I get the same output as you do in step 5.

The scanner works, after a fashion - Simple Scan does one page fine, but hangs on the second. However, it's fine if I run it in a terminal.

Comment: This worked for my Samsung Express C460FW. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. I have Lenovo B50 Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Samsung Xpress M2070W. Your scanner stuff saved my day, Thank you.

Comment: 18.04 and C480W - fix driver location and `sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4` did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Also i can add that only SimpleScan app was able to actually do scanning - https://launchpad.net/simple-scan . Dunno why the reason of this

Comment: I used `UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.39.tar.gz` driver version and it worked on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Your process worked for me for USB with M2070 with Ubuntu Eoan 19.10. Thanks for posting

Answer (score 12):

See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012?comments=all) of this problem and the [workaround that I posted in that bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012/comments/80). Let me sum it up here to help you out:

1. Link the files `libsane-smfp*` in the sane folder found at `/usr/lib/sane` to the sane folder found at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`.

   ```
   sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-smfp* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
   ```
2. As root, edit the file `59-smfp_samsung.rules` (you can find it in `/etc/udev/rules.d`) to include the following code/scanner number along with other Samsung model numbers which are already there:

   ```
   ATTRS{idProduct}=="2070", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
   ```

Voila. It should work like a charm.

I believe this bug mostly affects network scanners. Except with minor variations in the name/model numbers of other scanners, this workaround should work for other network scanners too. Check the bug-report link for Brother, Epson, and Xerox scanners.

Comment: I tried this solution but it wont work with my scanner over wifi.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. This made my Samsung SCX-3205W scanner connected over Wi-Fi work in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Following these 2 steps, I got my Samsung Xpress M2070 printer/scanner working on Ubuntu 18.04 again (connected via USB cable, no Wifi).

Answer (score 9):

For network Samsung scanners, put your scanner's IP address and optionally port anywhere in the file `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`:

```
tcp host_address [port]
```

It worked with my C460, probably would work also with other scanners, check the respective sane config file and settings here:

- [SANE supported devices](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/libsane/supported.html#Z-SAMSUNG)
- [sane-xerox_mfp man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-sane-xerox_mfp/)

Comment: Mine is connected by USB. How do I find out the relevant information?

Comment: Here is a good starting point for the usb configurationt: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-sane-usb/

Comment: that worked for me (without installing the Samsung driver), except that the printer/scanner is now waking up every time I start the system or plug in a USB device

Comment: Excellent, this worked for me with a Samsung SCX-3405FW wifi printer and scanner. and I'm on a new install of Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This worked for me for a M2070FW after a fresh Ubuntu 19.04 install. Note that the port for the scanner is 9400. If found that information here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=247495

Answer (score 3):

For a Samsung Scanner/Printer M2885FW, which is connected over WiFi, and Ubuntu 18.04 a combination of two suggestions in this thread solved the problem with scanning: [Rajasekharan N.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/979180/826920) and [Jevgenij Evll's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975485/826920).

1. I rebuilt the links found at /usr/lib/sane in the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane by using following lines:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so
   ```
2. After this step I un- and reinstalled the Samsung drivers.

Comment: Hi Marion! In your answer, can you include link(s) to the questions/answers that helped you?

Comment: The scanner is now detected by both Xsane and Simple Scan. However when I try to actually scan, Xsane returns the message "Failed tro start scanner: Error during device I/O" while Simple Scan says "Failed to start scan". Running in a terminal provides no information.

Comment: @Lolwhites. Have you tried to run xsane as a root to check if your problem could be a permission issue?

Comment: I found that plugging the scanner directly into a USB port instead of via a hub solved many of the issues, but I can still can't scan multiple pages.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I had to replace `libusb-0.1.so.4` with `libusb-dev` The command for this task is:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

Comment: I replaced libusb-0.1.so.4 with libusb-dev and now scanner works (`sudo apt-get install libusb-dev`). SAMSUNG m2070FW on Kubuntu 18.10

Comment: worked for me, Ubuntu 18.04, Samsung M2070W

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung M2070 printer/scanner, had the same problem as you, and I fixed the problem by uninstalling Ubuntu 18.04 and reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions in https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ and it solved my problem.

I installed keyring package http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/pool/debian/extra/su/suldr-keyring_2_all.deb using

```bsh
dpkg -i suldr-keyring_2_all.deb
```

and after adding the following apt source,

```bsh
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

I installed `suld-driver2-1.00.39` package:

```bsh
sudo apt install suld-driver2-1.00.39
```

From then on, `scanimage -L` and "simple scan" worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For my SAMSUNG M2070 running `uninstall-scanner.sh` and then `install-scanner.sh` again (with restarting afterwards) fixed the issue.
I also installed `libsane` and `sane-utils` from the proposed updates repo prior to the above, but not sure if this step is needed.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the driver didn't fix teh issue. I tries to get the latest version of sane via the ppa rolfbensch/sane-git androlfbensch/sane-release but the upgrade is held back.

Comment: Use the official aartful-proposed repo for getting the newer sane version (you can enable this repo in settings).

Comment: I removed the ppa and enabled the repo but the upgrade was still held back. I ran apt install libsane-common libsane-dev sane-utils and it worked, but now running Simple Scan causes a segfault and other programs like Xsane won't install because of dependency issues.

Comment: You don't need to install lisane-dev, but you need to install libsane1 from the experimental repo.

Comment: Actually, the latest libsane version has been released to updates 2 days ago, so you might get it from your regular repo.

Comment: I can't install libsane1 (on which Simple Scan depends) as it says:
Depends: libsane-common (= 1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1).
Trying to install ibsane-common produces the message :
libsane-common is already the newest version (1.0.27-artful1)

The aartful-proposed repo is enable in Software Sources.

Comment: Like I wrote, the regular updates repo got the new versions already, so you can try uninstalling all experimental stuff, disabling the experimental repo and reinstalling from your regular repo

Comment: I had pretty much given up on this as attempting to resolve the dependencies led to the system uninstalling things that I needed more, like gnome-control-center. Trouble was I couldn't figure out what I needed to undo. Any idea what I should try uninstalling an reinstalling after disabling the experimental repo?

Comment: Have freshly installed 18.04 but the issue persists.  The scanner is detected by sane-find-scanner but not scanimage -L:

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3469 [M2070 Series]) at libusb:002:002

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Rajasekharan N.'s](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969238/samsung-m2070w-scanner-no-longer-working-in-17-10/979180#979180) solution with Ubuntu 18.04 for Samsung 2070w and the [newest uld driver](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/SS/SL-M2070/uld_v1.00.37_00.99.tar.gz) downloaded from hp - scanner didn't work even connected via USB cable.

So

1. I removed the uld driver using the `uninstall.sh` provided with the uld driver
2. I reinstalled using the older Samsung uld driver (sadly I have no link for it) and it works again