# Saned denies access

Tags: networking, permissions, scanner

I followed the instructions in the [SANE daemon tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial) to set up a network scanner.

Everything should be set as needed. However, when I open xsane on a client PC (I tried more than one client, with the same result), the host saned denies access:

```
Feb  6 14:29:56 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: Started Scanner Service (xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:46488).
Feb  6 14:29:56 xxxxxxx saned[5122]: saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.26git starting up
Feb  6 14:29:56 xxxxxxx saned[5122]: check_host: access by remote host: localhost
Feb  6 14:29:56 xxxxxxx saned[5122]: init: access by host localhost denied
Feb  6 14:29:56 xxxxxxx saned[5122]: saned exiting
```

I'm puzzled here by the fact that the access request comes from 'localhost' instead of the client IP/name. If I indeed include localhost in the allowed IPs, the log changes into:

```
check_host: access by remote host: localhost
init: bad status=22 or procnum=6350304
```

I tried several things (add saned to lp and saned groups, modify saned@.service, define permission rules for saned), but nothing changes. Of course, the scanner works locally on the host. If, however, I add localhost both in saned.conf and in net.conf, I can connect to the scanner only locally, no second 'localhost' copy is detected by xsane (as mentioned in the tutorial for troubleshooting).

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem and running bionic (64bit) with included 1.0.27-1... no chance to make my scanner (C460FW) running.
any help appreciated, i checked all posts/manuals for this, something is really odd... the best post i found re this is https://askubuntu.com/questions/969238/samsung-scanner-no-longer-working-in-17-10/975485#975485 but also anything of this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several efforts, it seems that the solution came by upgrading sane-backends from 1.0.26git to 1.0.27git.

Answer (score 0):

think I found the missing pieces:
- package libusb-0.1-4 must be installed 
- /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 must have chmod a+x set

works like a charm now!
now backend smfp is found for the network scanner