# Samsung M2070FW printer/scanner worked on Ubuntu 16.04 but scanner is not detected on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner, samsung

Neither Simple Scan nor XSane detect my the scanning-function of my printer/scanner in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, even though it worked fine in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Printer function works though.  Help please.

I ran this command: sudo sane-find-scanner

Output was:
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3469 [M2070 Series]) at libusb:002:011

Please note that although I know how to run commands in terminal, my skill with Linux is relatively low.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Samsung scanner no longer working in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969238/samsung-scanner-no-longer-working-in-17-10)

Comment: The same problem in 20.04. "sane-find-scanner" finds my M2070W scanner but "scanimage -L" doesn't.