# canon MB2720 scanner works with 16.04 but not with 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner, canon

I have the most recent version (scangearmp2_3.40-1_amd64.deb) of the software from canon.    As the title says everything works fine for my installation with 16.04, but not for 18.04.     `sane-find-scanner` returns

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Realtek], product=0x8153 [USB 10/100/1000 LAN]) at libusb:004:003
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1792 [MB2700 series]) at libusb:003:003
```

However, `scangearmp2` returns `Cannot find available scanners`. `simple-scan` does no better.

I can print to the MB2720 via usb without problems.

Could somebody advise on how to proceed?

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059277/samsung-m2070fw-printer-scanner-worked-on-ubuntu-16-04-but-scanner-is-not-detect) suggests that this may in fact be an 18.04 bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround:  turn the printer off and on again.    After that, `scangearmp2` seems to find the Canon.