# How do I scan documents on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I have just installed (Samsung Xpress M2070) drivers, but I can't find out how to use printer scanning function on Ubuntu? How do I scan documents on Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Have you tried downloading Simple Scan from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: It doesn't recorgnise my printer, but it manages to print websites, using Firefox.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/969238/samsung-m2070w-scanner-no-longer-working-in-17-10 for several suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

i'm a newbie

but think you have to install SANE

then I scan in terminal with "scanimage >fileName.pnm"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Add information about how to install "SANE"